# Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-security

I couldn't update my app because the Google Play Store gave me this error;

> Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns.
>
> com.boomset.mobile.utils.t0->b

And the app doesn't have an encryption method in this file.

Any Idea in this case?

### EDIT 2

I removed my **Utils** file content from here. Because it was not related to Google Play's rejection.

I have a package that name is **Utils** and it has a file that do encryption.
Here is my **Encryptor** file.

Play Store gives me a link to solve this problem but I don't clearly understand it.

Thanks

```
public class Encryptor {

    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";

    private static final String initVector = "<our-vektor-key>"; // 16 bytes IV

    public static String encrypt(String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] key = Arrays.copyOfRange(AppPrefs.getEncryptionKey(), 0, 16);
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] key = Arrays.copyOfRange(AppPrefs.getEncryptionKey(), 0, 16);
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP));

            return new String(original);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: boomset makes requests to a web api, I assure you its using encryption in there.  But without code or a more detailed explanation of what the unsafe pattern is, its pretty hard to help.

Comment: Does it use md5 by any chance?

Comment: Hi @Pierre  I don't use any encryption in this file

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the actual code. But maybe you can ask the developer support for more help on this.

Comment: @Pierre I added my Utils file content.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's unclear. Are you sure it's this class?

Comment: You right @Pierre I misunderstood here. I have also utils package and it have a file that has do Encryption method. I will edit tomorrow 

Comment: Hi, @Pierre (and other guys) please look at EDIT 2. I updated my post. TY.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is related to [this support post](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/22512007/your-app-contains-unsafe-cryptographic-encryption-patterns?hl=en). I personally didn't know about this change though. It seems you cannot use static keys anymore like yours.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is using a static computed value for your init vector.

See https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9450925 for the full explanation:

> A statically computed value is a value that is the same on every
> execution of your app. Statically computed cryptographic values can be
> extracted from your app and used to attack your app’s encrypted data.
> Even if you manipulate keys, initialization vectors, and salts in
> complex ways prior to use, they remain unsafe if these manipulations
> are the same for every program execution.

Some of the recommended alternatives are listed as well, in particular:

> We recommend that you utilize Jetpack Security for symmetric
> cryptography. If your app encrypts API keys, personally identifiable
> information (PII), or other sensitive data, EncryptedSharedPreferences
> can be used to securely store this data without worrying about the
> implementation of secret keys, initialization vectors, and salts.

Comment: TY for your comment but I didn't understand how I change my code here? Can you able to share sample codes that are correct?

Comment: By the way, even if I find the right code, 
I can't test it unless upload to Play Store

@Pierre
I am trying to resolve this issue but how can I test it without upload to Play Store?